# Looping WHERE variable in SELECT statement for c#

Tags: c#, sql, webforms

So, I'm trying to create an area called "shoutout" where the current user may view "shoutout", basically messages from the shoutout table from people that are friends with him/her.

So, what I did was first put all the current user's friends into an array called "currentuserfriends", then I wish to select message from the shoutout table where username = all the users in "currentuserfriends".

However I have no idea how to loop in a select statement,

I don't want to have to do something like,

`string getuserfriendlist = "SELECT friend FROM friend WHERE username = '" + currentuserfriends[0] + "'";`

and increase currentuserfriends[0] manually. Is there a way to loop currentuserfriends until the end in a single select statement? Thanks.

**Friend table**

`username | friend`

**shoutout table**

`username | message | datetime`

**Code:**

```
        string[] currentuserfriends = new string[9999];
string[] posternames = new string[9999];
    string getuserfriendlist = "SELECT friend FROM friend WHERE username = '" + currentuser + "'";

    SqlCommand cmdb = new SqlCommand(getuserfriendlist, con);

    SqlDataReader drb;

    drb = cmdb.ExecuteReader();

    while (drb.Read())
    {

        string currentuserfriend = drb["friend"].ToString();
        currentuserfriends[l++] = currentuserfriend;
    }
    drb.Close();

    string getshoutout = "SELECT * FROM shoutout WHERE username = '" + currentuserfriends + "' AND username ='" + currentuser + "' order by datetime DESC";
    SqlCommand cmdc = new SqlCommand(getshoutout, con);
    SqlDataReader drc;
    drc = cmdc.ExecuteReader();

    while (drc.Read())
    {
        string postername = drb["username"].ToString();
        posternames[m++] = postername;
    }
    drc.Close();

    Label2.Text = posternames[0];
    Label3.Text = posternames[1];
    Label4.Text = posternames[2];
    Label5.Text = posternames[3];
    Label6.Text = posternames[4];
```

Comment: I would like to report a bug, I created a user account and now your website stopped working. My user name was `'; drop table shoutout; --` (please look in to using SqlParameters, do a search there are a lot of questions on this site about it.)

Comment: )))))))) sql injection makes my day!

Comment: On a on topic note, [here is a different, but related, question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321281/is-there-a-better-way-to-dynamically-build-sql-where-clause-than-by-using-1-1-at) that may solve your problem. **EDIT:** Another side question, what is with the arrays of size 9999? why not just use a `List<string>`?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I think a `drop table` is the least of your problems here. The real danger is someone taking over your server or [stealing all your data](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=44) without you knowing.

Comment: @Steven yea, but a drop table is the easiest to get the point across in the space of a comment, thanks for the link though, I will use it for a good example in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `List<string>` instead of an array. In that case you can do something like this:

```
var currentuserfriends = new List<string>();

while (drb.Read())
{
    currentuserfriends.Add(drb["friend"].ToString())
}
```

Like others said, you can optimize your query. I like to take it one step further and advice Entity Framework (or LINQ to SQL). It allows you to do this:

```
var db = new ObjectContext();

string[] currentuserfriends = (
    from friend in db.Friends
    where friend.Username == currentuser
    select friend.Name)
    .ToArray();
```

Saves you from having to hand craft your SQL queries and directly prevents your queries from SQL injection, since your current queries are currently vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Use the foreach loop on the array and then generate the SQL query

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to loop currentuserfriends until the end in a single
>   select statement?

Yes, there is. the [IN Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) does that.

Answer (score 0):

First make your array a comma seperated string using the following code

```
string idString = String.Join(",",currentuserfriends);
```

Then, Use the below sql statement

```
SELECT friend FROM friend WHERE username in ("+idstring+");
```